# Emacs Mode for a c-like language

Tags: emacs, colors, development-environment, indentation, auto-indent

I'm trying to write a new emacs mode for a new template c-like language, which I have to use for some academic research.

I want the code to be colored and indented like in c-mode, with the following exceptions:

- The '%' is not used as an operator, but as the first character in some specific keywords (like: "%p", "%action", etc.)
- The code lines do not end with a semicolon.

Is it possible to create a derived-mode (from c-mode) and set it to ignore the original purposes of '%' and ';'? Is it possible to make the feature of "automatic-indentation after pressing RET" work without ';'?

Are there similar modes for similar languages (with '{}' brackets, but without semicolons) that I could try to patch?

Should I try to write a major mode from scratch?

I thought about patching the R-mode from http://ess.r-project.org/, but this mode does not support comments of the form "/* comment */".

The most important feature that I'm looking for is the brackets-indentation, i.e. indenting code inside a '{}' block after pressing RET (and without the extra-indentation after lines that do not end with ';'). Partial solutions will help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind something *really* simple, you can look at [Gosu mode](http://gosu-lang.org/downloads/gosu-mode.el). Gosu is a language that has curly braces and no semi-colons, so you should be all set for your minimum. It also uses the same comment syntax as C.

The implementation of the mode for it is *really* simple and based on generic mode, so modifying it to work the way you want should be easy. It is *not* based on C-mode.

This is what I used to make a mode for the language I was working on for my compilers class, and it was really easy even with limited elisp experience. On the other hand, the indentation is fairly simple--it works for most code, but is not as complete as C-mode's.

Comment: Instead of using the Gosu mode, I used the [Google Go](http://golang.org) mode and patched it.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, CC-mode has been extended and generalized over time to accomodate ever more languages, and the latest CC-mode is supposed to be reasonably good at isolating the generic code from the language-specific code.  So take a look at some of the major modes that use CC-mode (e.g. awk-mode), and get in touch with CC-mode's maintainer who will be able to help you figure out hwo to do what you want.

Comment: I tried patching the CC-mode according to awk-mode (in which the lines do not have to end with ';') but it was too much code to understand and fix.

Answer (score 2):

Check out arduino-mode: https://github.com/bookest/arduino-mode/blob/master/arduino-mode.el

It is a C based mode that uses the cc-mode features to quickly create something very useful and unique to arduino programming.  Using this as a simple template should help a lot.